# In R, how do I append a categorical variable from one column if two data frames have a matching common ID?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames where the first (`df1`) has `siteID`, US state abbreviations `State`, and a continuous variable `Atemp`. The second (`df2`) has `siteID` and a continuous variable `Wtemp`. I would like for `df2` to have the `State` abbreviation found in df1, how can I do this?

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 11))
x <- c("siteID", "State", "Atemp")
colnames(df1) <- x
df1$siteID <- c(101,101,
                102,102,102,102,
                103,103,103,103,103)
df1$State <- c("AL","AL",
               "AK","AK","AK","AK",
               "TX","TX","TX","TX","TX")
df1$Atemp <- c("22","24",
               "10","4","2","7",
               "24","28","16","22","27")

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = 15))
y <- c("siteID", "Wtemp")
colnames(df2) <- y
df2$siteID <- c(101,102,101,103,103,
                102,101,102,103,101,
                102,102,101,103,103)
df2$Wtemp <- c(20,25,29,20,24,
                10,12,8,7,10,
                24,18,22,26,21)
```

The output should look like this:

```
   siteID State Wtemp
1     101    AL    20
2     102    AK    25
3     101    AL    29
4     103    TX    20
5     103    TX    24
6     102    AK    10
7     101    AL    12
8     102    AK     8
9     103    TX     7
10    101    AL    10
11    102    AK    24
12    102    AK    18
13    101    AL    22
14    103    TX    26
15    103    TX    21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `merge` could help

```
merge(df2, unique(subset(df1, select = -Atemp)), by = "siteID", all.x = TRUE)
```

which gives

```
   siteID Wtemp State
1     101    20    AL
2     101    10    AL
3     101    29    AL
4     101    22    AL
5     101    12    AL
6     102     8    AK
7     102    25    AK
8     102    18    AK
9     102    10    AK
10    102    24    AK
11    103    24    TX
12    103    20    TX
13    103     7    TX
14    103    26    TX
15    103    21    TX
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
unique(setDT(df1)[, .(siteID, State)])[setDT(df2), on = "siteID"]
```

gives

```
    siteID State Wtemp
 1:    101    AL    20
 2:    102    AK    25
 3:    101    AL    29
 4:    103    TX    20
 5:    103    TX    24
 6:    102    AK    10
 7:    101    AL    12
 8:    102    AK     8
 9:    103    TX     7
10:    101    AL    10
11:    102    AK    24
12:    102    AK    18
13:    101    AL    22
14:    103    TX    26
15:    103    TX    21
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    distinct(siteID, State) %>%    
    right_join(df2)
```